# metamask documentation for frontend development

Tags: metamask, documentation

Where can I find some valid documentation to understand what kind of parameters and call should I do in my javascript file in the html pages of a client to interact with deployed smart contracts through metamask?

For example I am trying to call a function of a smart contract with window.ethereum.request(*data*) but I don't understand how to structure "data"

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the official metamask docs to initialize for getting started:
https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/category/get-started/

For sending transactions, you can do it directly with metamssk building the transaction, or better. I would suggest you use a library like [ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/) that allows you to instantiate the contract and interact with it.

You can see some code snippets in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785630/how-to-connect-ethers-js-with-metamask/67836760#67836760

Hope it helps, and welcome to web3!